# SourceSafe CRC calculation

Tags: c#, version-control, visual-sourcesafe

Does anyone know what CRC checksum calculation is used in Microsoft SourceSafe? I want to calculate a checksum locally and compare it to the SourceSafe checksum.

I am using a CRC algorithm I found on the internet, but the seed or polynomial for the algorithm seems to be different for SourceSafe.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

See this post:

http://www.tesoga.com/vssnotes.html

The blurb you may be looking for is:

> And the 16-bit CRC is mostly the
>   standard algorithm. The one difference
>   is that in my experience, CRCs
>   typically start off by initializing
>   the state to -1 (0xFFFFFFFF),
>   accumulating, then returns the
>   logical-NOT of the result. However,
>   the VSS CRC logic initializes state to
>   0, and does not apply a logical-NOT at
>   the end. Make certain you're using
>   this technique when verifying any CRCs
>   in the file. (Refer to VssCrc32() in
>   CRC32.c for a working implementation.)

The code he mentions is included in this zip file:

http://www.teachsolaisgames.com/downloads/vsscode.zip

Comment: Thanks a lot, I converted the C++ code to C# code and it works.